# How do I create a new column based on multiple conditions from multiple columns?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, calculated-columns, multiple-conditions

I'm trying add a new column to a data frame based on several conditions from other columns.  I have the following data:

```
> commute <- c("walk", "bike", "subway", "drive", "ferry", "walk", "bike", "subway", "drive", "ferry", "walk", "bike", "subway", "drive", "ferry")
> kids <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
> distance <- c(1, 12, 5, 25, 7, 2, "", 8, 19, 7, "", 4, 16, 12, 7)
> 
> df = data.frame(commute, kids, distance)
> df
   commute kids distance
1     walk  Yes        1
2     bike  Yes       12
3   subway   No        5
4    drive   No       25
5    ferry  Yes        7
6     walk  Yes        2
7     bike   No         
8   subway   No        8
9    drive  Yes       19
10   ferry  Yes        7
11    walk   No         
12    bike   No        4
13  subway  Yes       16
14   drive   No       12
15   ferry  Yes        7
```

If the following three conditions are met:

```
commute = walk OR bike OR subway OR ferry
AND
kids = Yes
AND
distance is less than 10
```

Then I'd like a new column called get.flyer to equal "Yes". The final data frame should look like this:

```
   commute kids distance get.flyer
1     walk  Yes        1       Yes
2     bike  Yes       12       Yes
3   subway   No        5          
4    drive   No       25          
5    ferry  Yes        7       Yes
6     walk  Yes        2       Yes
7     bike   No                   
8   subway   No        8          
9    drive  Yes       19          
10   ferry  Yes        7       Yes
11    walk   No                   
12    bike   No        4          
13  subway  Yes       16       Yes
14   drive   No       12          
15   ferry  Yes        7       Yes
```

Comment: Please try to follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/38523589#38523589)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can use `%in%` for comparing multiple elements in a column, `&` to check if both conditions are TRUE.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(get.flyer = c("", "Yes")[(commute %in% c("walk", "bike", "subway", "ferry") & 
           as.character(kids) == "Yes" & 
           as.numeric(as.character(distance)) < 10)+1] )
```

---

It is better to create the `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as by default it is `TRUE`.  If we check the `str(df)`, we can find that all the columns are `factor` class.  Also, if there are missing values, instead of `""`, `NA` can be used to avoid converting the `class` of a `numeric` column to something else.

If we rewrite the creation of 'df'

```
distance <- c(1, 12, 5, 25, 7, 2, NA, 8, 19, 7, NA, 4, 16, 12, 7)
df1 <- data.frame(commute, kids, distance, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

the above code can be simplified

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(get.flyer = c("", "Yes")[(commute %in% c("walk", "bike", "subway", "ferry") &
        kids == "Yes" &
        distance < 10)+1] )
```

For better understanding, some people prefer `ifelse`

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate(get.flyer = ifelse(commute %in% c("walk", "bike", "subway", "ferry") & 
                kids == "Yes" &
                distance < 10, 
                          "Yes", ""))
```

This can be also done easily with `base R` methods

```
df1$get.flyer <- with(df1, ifelse(commute %in% c("walk", "bike", "subway", "ferry") & 
              kids == "Yes" & 
              distance < 10, 
                       "Yes", ""))
```

Comment: Note that the column names should be strings and not object references

Answer (score 10):

The solution is already pointed out by @akrun. I'd like to present it in a more 'wrapped up' way.

You can use the `ifelse` statement to create a column based on one (or more) conditions. But first you have to change the 'encoding' of missing values in the distance column. You used `""` to indicate a missing value, this however converts the entire column to `string` and inhibits numerical comparison (`distance < 10` is not possible). The `R` way of indicating a missing value is `NA`, your column definition of `distance` should be:

```
distance <- c(1, 12, 5, 25, 7, 2, NA, 8, 19, 7, NA, 4, 16, 12, 7)
```

The `ifelse` statement then looks like this:

```
df$get.flyer <- ifelse(
    ( 
        (df$commute %in% c("walk", "bike", "subway", "ferry")) &
        (df$kids == "Yes")                                     &
        (df$distance < 10)
    ),
    1,  # if condition is met, put 1
    0   # else put 0
)
```

*Optional:* Consider encoding your other columns in a different way as well:

- you could use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of "Yes" and "No" for the `kids` variable
- you could use a `factor` for commute

Answer (score 3):

Example, check if first_column_name is contained in second_column_name and write result to new_column

```
df$new_column <- apply(df, 1, function(x) grepl(x['first_column_name'], x['second_column_name'], fixed = TRUE))
```

Details:

```
df$new_column <- # create a new column with name new_column on df
apply(df, 1 # `1` means for each row, `apply(df` means apply the following function on df
function(x) # Function definition to apply on each row, `x` means input row for each row.
grepl(x['first_column_name'], x['second_column_name'], fixed = TRUE)) # Body of function to apply, basically run grepl to find if first_column_name is in second_column_name, fixed = TRUE means don't use regular expression just the plain text from first_column_name.
```