# Setting the value of one column based on three conditions of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns, `a` and `b`, and I would like to populate a third column, `c` based on the following three conditions:

- if `a.diff() > 0` then `c = b.shift() + b`
- elif `a.diff() < 0` then `c = b.shift() - b`
- elif `a.diff() == 0` then `c = b.shift()`

What is a Pythonic, one-liner way of doing this?

Example:

```
     a    b    c    
0    2   10  Nan
1    3   16   26
2    1   12    4
3    1   18   12
4    3   11   29
5    1   13   -2
```

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405628/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-based-on-multiple-conditions-from-multiple-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and cache [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed and [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html)ed `Series` for better performance and readibility:

```
diff = df.a.diff()
shifted = df.b.shift()

df['c'] = np.select([diff > 0, diff < 0], [shifted + df.b, shifted - df.b], default=shifted)
print (df)
   a   b     c
0  2  10   NaN
1  3  16  26.0
2  1  12   4.0
3  1  18  12.0
4  3  11  29.0
5  1  13  -2.0
```