# Create a new column based on conditions from other columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to do in Python something very similar as this question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405628/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-based-on-multiple-conditions-from-multiple-columns) R users. My intention is to create a new column that its values are created based on conditions from other columns

For example:

```
d = {'year': [2010, 2011,2013, 2014], 'PD': [0.5, 0.8, 0.9, np.nan], 'PD_thresh': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7]}
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I want to create a condition that says:

**pseudo-code:**

```
if for year X the value of PD is greater or equal to the value of PD_thresh
then set 0 in a new column y_pseudo 

otherwise set 1
```

My expected outcome is this:

```
df_temp 
Out[57]: 
   year   PD  PD_thresh  y_pseudo
0  2010  0.5        0.7       0.0
1  2011  0.6        0.7       0.0
2  2013  0.9        0.8       1.0
3  2014  NaN        0.7       NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html):

```
m1 = df_temp['PD'].isna()
m2 = df_temp['PD'].ge(df_temp['PD_thresh'])

df_temp['y_pseudo'] = np.select([m1, m2], [np.nan, 1], default=0)
print (df_temp)
   year   PD  PD_thresh  y_pseudo
0  2010  0.5        0.7       0.0
1  2011  0.6        0.8       0.0
2  2013  0.9        0.9       1.0
3  2014  NaN        0.7       NaN
```

Another solution is convert mask to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping and set only non missing rows by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
m2 = df_temp['PD'].ge(df_temp['PD_thresh'])
m3 = df_temp['PD'].notna()

df_temp.loc[m3, 'y_pseudo'] = m2[m3].astype(int)
print (df_temp)
   year   PD  PD_thresh  y_pseudo
0  2010  0.5        0.7       0.0
1  2011  0.6        0.8       0.0
2  2013  0.9        0.9       1.0
3  2014  NaN        0.7       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data d is different from your outcome, and I think you meant 1 if greater than the threshold, not the other way around, so I have this:

```
y = [a if np.isnan(a) else 1 if a>=b else 0 for a,b in zip(df_temp.PD,df_temp.PD_thresh)]
df_temp['y_pseudo'] = y
```

Output:

```
   year   PD  PD_thresh  y_pseudo
0  2010  0.5        0.7       0.0
1  2011  0.8        0.8       1.0
2  2013  0.9        0.9       1.0
3  2014  NaN        0.7       NaN
```